# Symfony2 customize form choice labels

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I want my choice labels rendered unescaped

here my FormType code:

```
$builder
    ->add('banner', new BannerType())
    ->add('runtime', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AdvertisingBundle:Runtime',
        'expanded' => true,
        'property' => 'label'
    ))
```

here the label property:

```
public function getLabel()
{
    return "<div class labelLeft>".$this->description.
    "</div><div class labelLeft>".$this->hint."</div>";
}
```

I want the label rendered raw, which form_theme fragment I need to override?

Comment: Have you tried `{{ form_label(...)|raw }}`?

Comment: you have asked for the form_theme fragment to override the look of a form_label that is a form_theme fragment :)
do you see the point?

Comment: it's true, but I found a simpler solution for customizing label

Answer (score 0):

here my solution:

```
        <table>
            {% for option in form.runtime %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="choiceColumn">
                        {{ form_widget(option) }}
                    </td>
                    {{ option.vars.label |raw}}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```